How to determine whether the system time is in 12 hour or 24-hour format in Android?
I want to determine whether the current system time is in 12 hour or 24-hour format, and have tried the following methods:
val is24Hour = Settings.System.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.System.TIME_12_24) == "24"

or
val is24Hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)

When the Use locale default in the system settings is turned off, they are correct.
However, when this switch is turned on, it will depend on the current Locale. How to correctly determine whether the current system is 12 hour or 24-hour?
This source code: is24HourFormat(Context context) also cannot correctly determine the system time format.

Use DateFormat.is24HourLocale(Locale) to determine if a given locale is 24 hours or not.  If you're not using the default locale, you just pass int he locale you are using rather than using the system one in the Context.

Thank you for your answer, it is indeed true. After changing to Resources.getSystem().configuration.locale, the result is correct.
